# Values in Pandas dataframe is mixed and shifted

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Values in Pandas dataframe is mixed and shifted.But each column has its own characteristics for values in it. How can I rearrange values in their own position?

1. 'floor_no' have to contain values with ' / ' substring in it.
2. 'room_count' is maximum 2 values digit long.
3. sq_m_count' have to contain ' m²' substring in it.
4. 'price_sq' have to contain ' USD/m²' in it.
5. 'bs_state' have to contain one of 'Have' or 'Do not have' values.

[Adding part of pandas dataframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k0Ak.png)

[image]

Comment: How did you get this DF? I guess it would be easier to fix the part where this DF gets constructed...

Comment: I fetched values based on XPath location on website.Website is not well-builded so there was bunch of problems with scrapping.What you see is 4 problematic columns, other 18 is absolutely normal.

Comment: Can you share an URL for testing?

Comment: https://bina.az/items/564994

Comment: are you parsing each real estate object separately?

Comment: Yes there is a long-long code with couple of functions. I made a list of RE objects and function in a loop which returns result to a list. List---> DF

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @Goyo .Fixed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out solution that is bit "+18 and perverty"
I wrote a loop that looks if each of these columns contain some sting that identifies columnt that it belongs to and copies this value to new column. Then i simply subsituted new with old one.

I did this with each of 'mixed' columns. This code filled my needs and fixed all problem. I understand how 'perverted' code is and will write a function that is much shorter and professional.

```html
for index in bina_az_df.itertuples():
    bina_az_df.loc[bina_az_df['bs_state'].str.contains(" m²|sot"),'new_sq_m_count'] = bina_az_df['bs_state']
    bina_az_df.loc[bina_az_df['sq_m_count'].str.contains(" m²|sot"),'new_sq_m_count'] = bina_az_df['sq_m_count']
    bina_az_df.loc[bina_az_df['floor_no'].str.contains(" m²|sot"),'new_sq_m_count'] = bina_az_df['floor_no']
    bina_az_df.loc[bina_az_df['price_sq'].str.contains(" m²|sot"),'new_sq_m_count'] = bina_az_df['price_sq']
    bina_az_df.loc[bina_az_df['room_count'].str.contains(" m²|sot"),'new_sq_m_count'] = bina_az_df['room_count']
```

```html
bina_az_df['sq_m_count'] = bina_az_df['new_sq_m_count'] # Substitutes
del bina_az_df['new_sq_m_count'] # deletes unnecesary temp column
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach:

```
In [90]: dfs = []

In [91]: url = 'https://ru.bina.az/items/565674'

In [92]: dfs.append(pd.read_html(url)[0].set_index(0).T)

In [93]: url = 'https://ru.bina.az/items/551883'

In [94]: dfs.append(pd.read_html(url)[0].set_index(0).T)

In [95]: df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
0    Категория Площадь Количество комнат Купчая
0  Дом / Вилла  376 м²                 6   есть
1  Дом / Вилла  605 м²                 6    нет
```